# using result of ng-repeat as a filter a JSON file

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON file like this:

```
"availableTimes": [
    {
      "date": "2018/07/02",
      "times": ["14","15","16", "17","18","19","20" ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2018/08/02",
      "times": [ "14", "15", "16", "17","18"]
    },
    {
      "date": "2018/09/02",
      "times": [ "14",  "15", "16", "17","18"]
    }      ],
  "reservedTimes": [
    {
      "date": "2018/07/02",
      "times": "14",          
    },
    {
      "date": "2018/08/02",
      "times": "15",

    }

  ]
```

I want to display all available times by buttons but the button was disabled if this time was in reserved time.
I want to write with ng-repeat, but I don't know how can do this???!!
For example:

```
        <div ng-repeat="x in sp.availableTimes|filter:{'date':visitData}">
              <div ng-repeat="t in x.times">
                   <button ng-disable="dis(t)">
                     // disabled button if t is in s.reservedTimes.times
                   </button>

              </div>
        </div>
```

in the controller we have:

```
 $scope.dis = function (time) {

      angular.forEach($scope.sp.reservedTimes, function (value, key) {
          if ( value.times == time)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      });
```

But this is not working correctly!

Comment: Please provide a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a json object to reference your json file. Afterwards you can parse through the data in  your HTML to retrieve the required times.

```
<ul ng-repeat = "let c of object">
  <li>
    <button>
      {{c.reservedTimes.times}}>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>
      {{c.availableTimes.times}}>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't use ionic, Any other idea ?!

Comment: It is the same premise with Angular. The syntax is a bit different though. Please see the edited HTML.

Comment: Thank you Ivas, My problem is to show "availableTimes" of a specific date with buttons and disable those buttons that are in ReservedTimes on that date.I my example, for date: "2018/07/02"  we have seven buttons: "14","15","16", "17","18","19","20",  button "14" should be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried adding this line ng-disabled="all" ?